# Hudson won't execute windows batch commands after running a .bat script

Tags: batch-file, automation, hudson

In hudson, after running a .bat script my slave refuses to run anything that comes afterward. It instead just said that it finished with a success.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Trying do a

```
call yourscript.bat
```

instead of just a

```
yourscript.bat
```

Comment: Thanks! This worked great, hudson and I seem to fight on the daily.

Comment: Zack: That's `cmd`'s behavior there.